# On hover, show image at the right of a div

Tags: css, jquery

I have a list of action (Create a free account, view stats, etc.). Here is how it's look like.

```
        <div class="box_go">
            <div class="ico"><img src="img/ico/arrow_f.png" width="16" /></div>
            <h3>Get a free account</h3>
            <p>And start earning points</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_go">
            <div class="ico"><img src="img/ico/arrow_f.png" width="16" /></div>
            <h3>View stats</h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
```

I want that a little arrow (div.ico) appear at the right of the parent div on hover.
Using jQuery... but when I hover on the first element, both arrows shows up...

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: while you can use jQuery there is no reason to it can be done purely in CSS. Please show your CSS and jQuery that you are using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use CSS?

```
.box_go {
    position: relative;
}

.box_go .ico {
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   display: none;
}

.box_go:hover .ico {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yeah its working and its a very good idea... But using jquery will be more cross-browser so ill use this for now but if someonw could find any way to do it using jQuery, that would be great.

Comment: jQuery is slower and more error-prone, but I grant that it will work in IE6. That's the only browser you gain by doing this with jQuery though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="matter">Matter written</span>
<span id="ico">image.ico</span>

$('#ico').hide();

$('#matter').mouseover(function() {
    $('#ico').show();
});

$('#matter').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#ico').hide();
});
```

Comment: @domenic check my altered answer

Comment: I think you'd want to use mouseenter paired with mouseleave, rather than mouseover.

Comment: and its more like <span id="matter">Matter written <span id="ico">image.ico</span></span> and i have this multiple times... so it will show every span instead of the selected one.